# Releasing a key under a specific time reset the sequence?

Tags: sequence, autohotkey, release

So i got this code its working fine. Its for a sword fighting game.

If i hold down the left mouse button (LMB) it will send the key 5 (slash attack) and if i release the LMB it send the key 7 (feint). Same goes for the key 6 (overhead attack) and if i release the LMB it send the key 7 (feint).

So the sequence is like this 5,6,5,6 etc. working like a charm.

If i dont press the LMB for 1,5 sec the sequence reset itself. So its always be like 5,5,5,5 etc. Its working fine too.

Here is the working code for this:

```
*lbutton::
    send % Seqkeys("5","6")
    KeyWait, lbutton
    Send, 7
return

Seqkeys(params*){ 
    static s:=0, c:=0, t:=1500
    max := params.MaxIndex()
    (A_TickCount-s<=t && (c+=1)<=max) ? c : c:=1, s:=A_TickCount
    return params[c]
}
```

Now what i want to achieve is that if i release the LMB under 0.3 sec it should always reset the
sequence and send 5,5,5,5 etc.
If the release was over 0.3 sec the sequence should work as default 5,6,5,6 etc.

Sry for the bad english hope u can understand. thx :)

Comment: Try replacing t:=1500 with t:=300, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: hey! in the game the sword swing release time is like 1,2 sec so i setup it to 1,5 sec cause if i wanna use combo attack its always gonna be 5,6,5,6 etc. if i setup it to 300, than my combo always reset to 5,5,5,5 etc. and its not good. 
i want only 5,5,5,5 if i release the lmb under 0,3 sec.

Comment: because when im holding down the lmb the charachter swinging the sword, if i let go the lmb charachter stops the swinging. god i need to learn english someday :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have what you need:

```
global s:=0, c:=0, t:=1500, t2:=1000/3

*lbutton::
    send % Seqkeys("5","6")
    KeyWait, lbutton
    If (A_TickCount-s < t2)
        c := 0
    Send, 7
return

Seqkeys(params*) { 
    global s, c, t
    max := params.MaxIndex()
    (A_TickCount-s<=t && (c+=1)<=max) ? c : c:=1
    s := A_TickCount
    return params[c]
}
```

Example:

```
Button down: 5
Button up (down for 0.5s): 7
Button down: 6
Button up (down for 0.5s): 7
Button down: 5
Button up (down for 0.2s): 7
Button down: 5
Button up (down for 0.2s): 7
Button down: 5
Button up (down for 0.5s): 7
Button down: 6
Button up (down for 0.5s): 7
```

Comment: Hey D. Pardal! i tried to get help to further tweak this code can u help me again? here is the link for the question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64796721/how-to-reset-a-key-sequence-with-a-specific-key